# How to display the start situation in an xskakloop

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak

How can I display the start situation, for example the normal chessboard structure, in an xskakloop?
So to speak as "Move 0".

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\setchessboard{showmover=false, margin=false}

\begin{document}
\section{Start situation :)}
\newchessgame
\chessboard[tinyboard]

\section{Loop has no start situation :(}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 g6 3.Nc3 Bg7}

\xskakloop[step=1]{%
\begin{tabular}{c}
\chessboard[tinyboard,
setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
\\
\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
\end{tabular}\quad}%
\end{document}
```